# about TTY head bolts 1990 Toyota corolla 2e wagon manual shift with carburettor

Tags: cylinder-head, bolts

I need to know if the torque spec is done in one sweep of the torque wrench or gradually quarter turn at a time up to the first 22ft lbs and then gradually again to 36ft lbs. and then 90 degrees. Thank you. Frank.So far I have not be able to obtain a repair manual for this vehicle. What I need to be sure about mostly: Is torquing done in one sweep of the torque wrench up to the torque specs or do a small turn at a time to torque specs and then finally click the wrench at the specs. Different techs seem to have different ways of doing it, so that is why it is a confusing issue for me.I understand that the specs are 22ftlbs 36ftlbs and then 90 degrees torque angle.And the bolt-threads and the washers/head have to be clean and oiled and so on. Thank you Frank

Comment: Gradual is always better, working from the center bolts to the outer ones in a diagonal criss cross pattern.

Comment: Some engines have a specific pattern - check the workshop manual...

Comment: Impossible to answer without more details - the vehicle or fastener OEM will have information regarding the proper procedure, pattern, specific lubrication (or lack of), and perhaps even a final torque after operating temperature and the head gasket seats.  An angle torque does not automatically mean the fastener is TTY.